# Complexity of an function that has no guarantee of finishing.

Tags: performance, time, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Given a very simple function looking like:

```
List<double> l = new ArrayList<double>();
addUniqueToList(){  
    double n = math.random();
    while (l.contains(n)){
        n = math.random();
    }
    l.add(n);
    return;
}
```

How would you go about assigning a complexity to the algorithm? After the list contains a large number of elements, there is no guarantee that the algorithm will ever finish. How would this be expressed in big O notation?

Comment: Duplicate question?  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/283848/big-o-notation-of-randomness

Comment: Big O provides an upper bound on the asymptotic time complexity. Since there is no hard upper bound, it would be O(infinity).